# Identifying page break from byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, pdfbox

I have a use case where I am downloading a large file by writing the bytes to ServletOutputStream, and I would like to return some specified pages without completely loading file in-memory and using a library.

1. Is it possible to identify the page break from the byte stream?
2. If yes, what should be the correct approach?

**Edit**
The file was created and stored using Apache PDFBox.

Comment: I would think that you should be using char[] rather than byte[] if you're using strings.

Comment: What is a "page break" in a binary file? E.g. a GIF image file doesn't have page breaks. An MP3 music file does have page breaks. A Java source file doesn't have page breaks.

Comment: which means page breaks are format-specific and it is inserted by libraries while converting from binary to a specific format?

Comment: please explain what you are trying to accomplish further, if possible with a concrete example. By "page break", do you mean a form feed character? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break)

Comment: I need to serve the user with specified pages from a PDF doc, here the whole PDF is not required and only a portion of it needed to be downloaded. and I am not loading the complete PDF in memory. so I was thinking to get the page break from stream and return only if the current page is required.

Comment: I think that will generally not work. PDFs probably do not use page break characters, or at least you cannot break their pages apart by merely inspecting the bytes. Not to mention that you will probably corrupt the structure of the PDF by doing so - there may be references, ToC and whatnot

Comment: PDF isn't like HTML. It doesn't work that easily. Some PDF are "linerarized" so that not all has to be loaded, but PDFBox doesn't support that.

Comment: How different Document libraries and readers insert a page break?

Comment: They don't "insert" it. Each page is an object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but I am more confused now.

Comment: If you only need a few pages, why don't you load the PDF with PDFBox, cut down the file in-memory to only those pages, and save the reduced PDF to the result stream.

Comment: it will consume some memory to load the File completely.

Comment: If memory is such a concern and if you don't want to serve too many pages to the user, why don't you simply create smaller PDFs to start with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to identify the page break from the byte stream?

No. For the simple reason that there is no page break in the byte stream.

PDF files contain numerous objects (fonts, colorspaces, bitmaps, ...) which can be used on multiple pages. In some PDFs all pages even share all resources. Thus, you don't have a section in the PDF byte array used for a page and only that page.

Furthermore, those objects are referenced via cross reference streams or tables by their offset in the file. So only serving the regions of the byte stream that are needed for some given pages cannot work to start with as the offsets would be wrong then.

Theoretically one could determine the regions in a PDF byte stream which are *not* used by those given pages and transfer `0`s instead. If you employ some transport compression, these regions would compress quite well. But to determine those regions, you'd need a PDF library which you don't want to do.

Alternatively, there is a special way to save PDF files optimized for partial file access (files so saved are called "linearized"), but that doesn't help you either as PDFBox does not offer saving PDFs like that and because making use of that optimization requires support of HTTP ranges which are seldom supported in servlet containers or servlets themselves.

---

IMO your best option is to change the production of the large file to produce the smaller files you want instead of (or in addition to) the large file.

Answer (score 3):

***What you asked***

Having the PDF document, you can write code that creates a small PDF document with just one single page. A 10 page PDF would give 10 single PDFs, together much more bytes than the original PFD.

This is disappointing, there is no easy paging system I am aware of.

***Around PDF streaming***

One can generate a PDF optimized for the web streaming:

- sequential, in-order presentation of elements
- image data in front before it is used
- best use the standard fonts, they are already present with the PDF viewer.
  embedded fonts only transmitting the used characters comes second best, but
  is not suited for PFD forms.
- PDFBox and its capability for linearized PDFs I unaware of, but it might be sufficient to create the PDF in-order.

An of course page logos and such need only be defined once.

Images must have an adequate solution for printing.

Vector graphics can be ideal (eps, svg).